# jquery polling data (call for suggestions to use)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

For a current project I would need to perform the following steps, after user clicks a button:

> 1.)->make a AJAX request to a script to get a random ID & 6 URLs from
>
> 2.)->make 6 request to the URLs I get from the script
>
> 3.)->perform a check to the script from step1 using the random ID as identifier to receive some data after the 6 requests were made

What's the best way to do so using javascript on client-side?

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: I'm looking for some suggestions, I think about using XMLHttpRequest. But I would need to show a loading gif image while performing the checks described above. That's why I ask for some suggestions on how to do this.